# Data_Wrap_Struct and destruction order

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, ruby-c-extension

I'm writing an Ruby extension for a physics engine. This physics engine has **bodies** that are linked to a **world**, so my Ruby objects are `World` and `Body`. A body is constructed (in C++) with `world->CreateBody` and destroyed with `world->DestroyBody`.

The problem is that the Ruby GC is destroying the world before the bodies. So, when the GC destroy the bodies, the world no longer exists and I get a segmentation fault. I know that I need to mark something somewhere for the GC (using `rb_gc_mark`), but I don't know where.

---

The `World` class is pretty standard, it looks like this:

```
extern "C" void world_free(void *w)
{
    static_cast<World*>(w)->~World();
    ruby_xfree(w);
}

extern "C" void world_mark(void *w)
{
    // ???
}

extern "C" VALUE world_alloc(VALUE klass)
{
    return Data_Wrap_Struct(klass, world_mark, world_free, ruby_xmalloc(sizeof(World)));
}

extern "C" VALUE world_initialize(VALUE self)
{
    World* w;
    Data_Get_Struct(self, World, w);
    new (w) World();
    return self;
}
```

The `Body` class is a little different, since it needs to be created from a World object (I can't simply `new` it). So it looks like this:

```
extern "C" void body_free(void* b)
{
    Body* body = static_cast<Body*>(b);
    World* world = body->GetWorld();
    world->DestroyBody(body);
}

extern "C" void body_mark(void* b)
{
    // ???
}

extern "C" VALUE body_alloc(VALUE klass)
{
    return Data_Wrap_Struct(klass, body_mark, body_free, 0);
}

extern "C" VALUE static_obj_initialize(VALUE self, VALUE world)
{
    Body* b;
    World* w;

    Data_Get_Struct(self, Body, b);
    Data_Get_Struct(world, World, w);

    b = w->CreateBody();
    DATA_PTR(self) = b;

    return self;
}
```

---

So my questions are:

1. Which of the two objects should I mark on the GC?
2. How do I do it? Do I simply mark with `rb_gc_mark`, or should I do it only under some conditions? Which ones?
3. What should I mark? The mark functions receive only a naked pointer to my struct, but the `rb_gc_mark` function expects a `VALUE`.

Comment: I don’t think `rb_gc_mark` will help here — if the entire world-body structure becomes unreachable then there is no way (as far as I know) to control the order that the free functions are called. The problem is that the function to free a `Body` depends on the existence of the corresponding `World`. It looks like the C++ API of the library doesn’t map cleanly onto a Ruby API where `Worlds` and `Body`s are independent objects — you may need to rethink how the objects are created and handled, and their lifecycles.

Comment: I see. The problem is that the objects are in a external library - that is, I have no control over it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to register the `VALUE` of `World` as busy tied to the lifecycle of **all** instances of `Body` tied to it.

This means that when they are created, you'll want to do something like this:

```
extern "C" VALUE static_obj_initialize(VALUE self, VALUE world)
{
    Body* b;
    World* w;

    Data_Get_Struct(self, Body, b);
    Data_Get_Struct(world, World, w);

    b = w->CreateBody();
    DATA_PTR(self) = b;
    rb_gc_register_address(&world);

    return self;
}
```

The you'd want to unregister when the `Body` is destroyed:

```
extern "C" void body_free(void* b)
{
    Body* body = static_cast<Body*>(b);
    World* world = body->GetWorld();
    world->DestroyBody(body);
    rb_gc_unregister_address(&world); //almost right
}
```

This isn't quite accurate, however, because `rb_gc_unregister_address()` wants a `VALUE *`. You should be able to write a simple wrapper (or use std::pair<>) that'll carry the World `VALUE`.

*Caveat: I haven't tested any of the above code, but it should be directionally correct.*